# When does property value set in Swift class?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Say there is a **UIViewController** with property
`private var counter = 1`.
Does this property get its value once when class is loaded into memory or every time `viewDidLoad()` method calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called only on instanatiation so it's only called once by objected created. 
So it's the same.

Answer (score 3):

`viewDidLoad` has nothing to do with initialisation of properties. Property is initialised only once when class is initialised. It is the reason why non-optional properties have to be initialised directly or in constructor.

`viewDidLoad` is just regular function and even you call it directly, properties stay untouched (if they are not changed in this method).

`viewDidLoad` is part of lifecycle of ViewControllers and it is called only once when you create the class and load from xib. It is reason why this method is great for initial setup...

Answer (score 0):

As just described before :

- `viewDidLoad` usually used for init setup of the ViewController and variables if it's necessary.
- `deinit` usually used to set `nil` of each ViewController's variable used.